# Greenplum - Can't drop table

Tags: ddl, greenplum

I have distributed version of Greenplum v4.3.4 (2 masters, 3 slaves with 4 segments per server).

One of slaves ran out of disk space, which has been fixed.
Now whenever I want to drop table I'm getting the following error:

```
DB=# DROP TABLE schema.table;
ERROR:  Did not find gp_relation_node entry for relation name pg_toast_296952_index, relation id 296955, relfilenode 19525314 (relcache.c:650)  (seg7 10.0.0.9:40007 pid=6551) (cdbdisp.c:1528)
```

I tried to run in utility mode:

`$GPHOME/bin/lib/gpcheckcat -p 5432 -B>checkcat_B.out 2>&1 &`

yet it does not create any repair scripts.
Is there a way to easily fix this issue?

Comment: try: drop table <table name> cascade;

Comment: Or: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <table name>;

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but they did not worked.
I'm getting the same error unfortunately